# is it possible to overload std::chrono::duration_cast?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a device that reports time as integer seconds and fractional seconds in clock ticks. For this particular device, the clock operates a 256MHz. I've defined a custom resolution that I use in duration and time_points:

```cpp
using Res = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 256'000'000>>;
```

(unless it is pertinent, I'd rather not debate uint vs int).

This resolution is adequate for representing times since 1970, with overflow around 2763.

Given,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    using Res = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 256'000'000>>;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using TimePoint = time_point<system_clock, Res>;

    auto s_now = system_clock::now();

    auto simple = time_point_cast<Res>(s_now);

    auto s_sec = duration_cast<seconds>(s_now.time_since_epoch());
    auto hard = TimePoint(Res(s_sec));
    hard += duration_cast<Res>(s_now.time_since_epoch() - s_sec);

    std::cout << "s_now  " << s_now.time_since_epoch().count() << "\t" << s_sec.count() << "\n"
              << "simple " << simple.time_since_epoch().count() << "\t" << duration_cast<seconds>(simple.time_since_epoch()).count() << "\n"
              << "hard   " << hard.time_since_epoch().count()  << "\t" << duration_cast<seconds>(hard.time_since_epoch()).count() << "\n"
;
    return 0;
}
```

then `simple` is not equal to `hard`. The output might be something like this:

```
s_now  1628286679505051812  1628286679
simple 121693484773940438   475365174
hard   416841389953293263   1628286679
```

What happens is that `time_point_cast` [overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60425292/9220132) the `int` Rep for `system_clock::duration`.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226923/9220132 it would seem that this is legal and moral, but it does not taste great. This limitation is a much too easy to produce source of bugs.

If there were a way for me to define the implementation of casting to my very high resolution type such that I protect against overflow, that would be ideal. Knowing to use a custom helper function instead of casting is just asking for trouble, because someone will forget some time and the bug might go unnoticed into production.

Comment: I am not sure I understood you question, but adding something to `std` is very illegal aka UB, except where not explicitly allowed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541022/what-are-the-reasons-that-extending-the-std-namespace-is-considered-undefined-be

Comment: understood. However, in some circumstances it is legal to provide template specializations for user-defined types. I'm hoping the answer lies in that direction.

Comment: Yes it is allowed for `std::hash` but it has to be allowed. One could try to find it on cppreference.com. Otherwise one has to read the standard i.e. the free draft, which you can find via the FAQ of said site. I would look to but its bedtime for me.

Comment: @Superlokkus As long as there's a user defined type involved, making specializations in `std` is perfectly ok ( and `std::hash<user_defined_type>` is one commonly used example) - I'm not sure that this applies in this case though but it might.

Comment: However, `std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 256'000'000>>` is not a user-defined type, any more than (say) `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @MarshallClow I agree - it's not, but it's also not placed in `std` - it's a perfectly valid typedef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree you hit overflow.  But it isn't because `system_clock::rep` is `int`.  Indeed your `system_clock::rep` is `int64_t`, and yes it does overflow for this operation.

Your `system_clock::period` is `nano`.  And the conversion factor to convert `nano` to `std::ratio<1, 256'000'000>` is <sup>32</sup>/<sub>125</sub>.  And 32 * 1628286679505051812 overflows the common `rep` : `uint64_t`.

There are several ways to avoid the overflow and get the  correct answer.  And you show one of them.  Another way is to use 128 bit arithmetic, which is available on your platform:

```
using D = duration<__int128_t>;
auto s_now = system_clock::now() + D{0};  // s_now::rep is now 128 bits
```

This changes the output to:

```
s_now  1628286679505051812  1628286679
simple 416841389953293263   1628286679
hard   416841389953293263   1628286679
```

Finally, to answer your question:  No, don't override `duration_cast`.  Instead create `your_cast` and do whatever you want with it.  C++17 already does this itself by introducing three new "flavors" of `duration_cast`/`time_point_cast` which simply change the default rounding mode:

```
template<class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
  constexpr ToDuration floor(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
template<class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
  constexpr ToDuration ceil(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
template<class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
  constexpr ToDuration round(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);

template<class ToDuration, class Clock, class Duration>
  constexpr time_point<Clock, ToDuration> floor(const time_point<Clock, Duration>& tp);
template<class ToDuration, class Clock, class Duration>
  constexpr time_point<Clock, ToDuration> ceil(const time_point<Clock, Duration>& tp);
template<class ToDuration, class Clock, class Duration>
  constexpr time_point<Clock, ToDuration> round(const time_point<Clock, Duration>& tp);
```

[Here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) are example implementations of these functions.  Just copy one, choose an appropriate name for `your_cast`, and implement it however works best for you.